# Android Studio 0.8.2 corrupt installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I started working with android development last month and installed android studio version 0.60, update to 0.8 beta as it arrived and to 0.8.2 a few days back. Now i am getting a message saying that my installation is corrupt, all my projects are showing error(red marks on each resource)

http://s4.postimg.org/v9p6wuet9/corrupt.png

So I dutifully followed the advised , removed and re installed android studio (I cleared all directories used by android studio) but I'm still getting the same error messages

Please help

Comment: Can you sum up the folders you've removed?

Comment: c:\androidstudioprojects, c:\users\akshit\.androidstudiopreview, c:\users\akshit\.androidstudiobeta , c:\users\akshit\.gradle,c:\users\akshit\appdata\local\androidstudio

Comment: I also cleared temporary files and restarted my laptop before re-installing

Comment: That seems to be the full list indeed. Can you confirm or refute the claim that `plugins/android-designer` exists? What if you delete it?

Comment: Instead of installing using the installer, you could also try to extract the zip from [here](http://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/0.8.2/android-studio-ide-135.1267975-windows.zip), and try to run it. Note that this package does not contain the SDK, make sure you copy the SDK folder from your existing installation.

Comment: No, there is no folder plugins/android-designer in the main directory of the IDE.i had already checked that. however, the corrupt message only shows"plugins/android-designer" and not the full path of the folder, that might be possible that this folder is in some other temporary directory. i also tried searching for this directory using windows explorer search but got no results . still the IDE shows same error. i will try the zip file now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My android studio was installed in /usr/share/android-studio (linux). In this directory, there was a folder `plugins`. Inside, there was `android-designer`. Delete it and the message disapears.

Answer (score 6):

delete the "/android-studio/plugins/android/android-designer" folder, if there Archiving two "builder-model-0.xx.0.jar" you should also delete the oldest file in the folder "/plugins/android/lib".

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! But the correct path (on Windows at least) is "/android-studio/plugins/android-designer" and the correct name of the file is "builder-model-0.xx.0.jar" :)

Comment: Thank @Renan Ferrari, the right name is "builder-model-0.xx.0.jar"

Comment: Helps new versions too. I got the same error when extracted **Android Studio 2.0 Preview** into my existing installation directory. For me the path is `\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib` and I'm on **Windows**